# Ansible: Unable to ping on windows node [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ssl, ansible, winrm

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 virtuell machine and a two MS Windows Server 2008 R 2 virtuell machine.

I follow [this](http://darrylcauldwell.com/how-to-setup-an-ansible-test-lab-for-windows-managed-nodes-custom-windows-modules/) instructions until "Once we have these two files setup, we can look to test connectivity". Now I want to ping the windows VMs. I get after the comman an error, but I dont know wy.

*Execution:*

```
stefan@ansible-server:~/ansible_test$ ansible windows -i host -m win_ping
```

*Answer:*

```
[IP-ADRESS] | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "ERROR! ssl: 500 WinRMTransport. [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:"
}
[IP-ADRESS] | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "ERROR! ssl: 500 WinRMTransport. [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:"
}
```

Do u know wy it didn't work?

Comment: whats the python version on the host/target machines ?

Comment: I have installed the python version 2.7.12. It still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the solution, but i am not **satisfied**, because it's for me not the proper solution, but it works.

Create in the folder ansible_test:

```
mkdir callback_plugins
nano callback_plugins/fix-ssl.py
```

Write in the file:

```
import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_default_https_context') and hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

class CallbackModule(object):
    pass
```

Run:

```
 ansible windows -i host -m win_ping -vvvvv
```

Result:

```
10.92.0.38 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "win_ping"
    },
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To be able to provision windows Machines you need to run this power shell in windows machines, first to generate cert files for winrm.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

Comment: I have already run this script. The script execute successful, but the connectivity between host/target didn't work.